# Java compile and run swing application

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile and run a java swing application from command line. 
I set the path to `jdk1.8.0_102` but I receive these errors:

[image: errors]

how I can fix that? I can compile and run the application in IntelliJ without any problem. Is there a online java IDE which supports swing applications?

**EDIT**
After I set the path:

> javac version 1.6.0_45
>   java version "1.8.0_181"

Comment: Please edit your question to include the source code and the error message. Don't add the source code as image.

Comment: Also, add the output of `javac -version` and `java -version` to your question.

Comment: Note that output indicates there is over 380 lines of code being compiled. A general tip: Compile early and compile often. But also heed the advice of @Progman & always post the **text** of the code and error messages.

Comment: It looks like an earlier version of javac is in the path variable _before_ the version 1.8. I am not familiar with the Windows command prompt but it looks like you are adding the path to the java 8 compiler at the end of the path variable. Do you still have this problem if you add the path to the java 8 compiler at the start of the path variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After I set the path: javac version 1.6.0_45 java version "1.8.0_181"

Well you have two versions on your computer. The JDK 1.6 is defined first in your path. Get rid of that version.

In Windows 7 you can configure the path permanently by doing:

1. go to Control Panel
2. select System
3. Click on Advance System Settings
4. Click on Environment Variables
5. Find the "path" variable and edit it. Remove the JDK1.6 and add the JDK 1.8

Now every time you open a command window the path will already be set.

Note you should also do this for the "classpath" as well.

Or as a temporary fix when you open the command window just use:

```
set path="jdk8 path;"%path%
```

so JDK1.8 is found before jdk1.6.

Answer (score -1):

For the IDE you can use Eclipse with extension GUI Designer plugin and Netbeans. these IDE's got drag and drop features.